# Linq query for getting group by values in columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have total 3 tables in which I have data as

1. Vendor master table has list of vendors
2. Category master table that has list of categories.
3. Product master table that has product details and foreign key of Vendor by which this product is supplied and foreign key of Category in which this product comes. Data in this table is as below:

[image]

When I grouped the data with Category and Vendor wise after joining the tables, I got the result as below

[image]

Now what I required is to show the summarized data that shows Vendor wise Product in each category and its Total in last column and I required this data to show in below format, so that if in future I create one more Vendor then it will create another column of that Vendor and its value also added in Total in last column.

[image]

So this output I need from LINQ query in C# which I can execute on my DB which is connected using entity framework, so that I can bind it to my datatable.

Comment: It is called PIVOT query which is not suitable with LINQ. Maybe you just need control which supports such view? Like DevExpress PivotGrid?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: so can I create Json output i.e. array of row wise data in required manner, after fetching the records from DB using the LINQ?

Comment: Search SO for LINQ and PIVOT. For sure you can generate such JSON. But I'm afraid   it will be not pure LINQ query.

Comment: Also, PIVOT Query. is supported by many databases and maybe just write SQL will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void Main()
{
    var orders = new List<Order>(){
        {new Order("C1","P1","V1")},
        {new Order("C1","P2","V1")},
        {new Order("C1","P3","V1")},
        {new Order("C2","P4","V1")},
        {new Order("C2","P5","V1")},
        {new Order("C3","P1","V2")},
        {new Order("C3","P2","V2")},
        {new Order("C3","P4","V2")},
        {new Order("C1","P6","V2")},
        {new Order("C1","P7","V2")},
    };
    var q = orders
        .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(x => new{
            Category = x.Key,
            V1 = x.Count(y => y.Vendor == "V1"),
            V2 = x.Count(y => y.Vendor == "V2"),
            Total = x.Count()
        });
}
public class Order
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public string Vendor {get;set;}
    public Order(string category,string product,string vendor)
    {
        Category = category;
        Product = product;
        Vendor = vendor;
    }
}
```

Might not be the most universal solution, but it may be useful in certain limited cases, specifically when the number of columns is small.    Which by the way is the case if the pivot table is to be reported.

Also, note that Vendors would not be my preferred candidates for columns.